# Change onscreen position of textview

Tags: android, android-layout, position, android-relativelayout, textview

I am making a quiz app. For displaying the MCQ questions, I have used the following **layout**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/vg">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:text="Question"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/option1_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="62dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/question_textView"
        android:text="Option 1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/option2_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/option1_textView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/option1_textView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/question_textView"
        android:text="Option 2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/option4_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/option2_textView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:text="Option 4"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/option3_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/option4_textView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/option4_textView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/option1_textView"
        android:text="Option 3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am parsing an XML to get the questions, options and the correct answer. When the user selects the correct option for a particular question, the TextView s are getting updated with the next question and its respective options. This is how I am doing it:

```
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_MCHOICE);
            // looping through all item nodes <item>
            for ( i = 0; i < nl.getLength();i++) {

                loop_checker=i;
//          while(counter< nl.getLength())
//          {
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                Element e = (Element) nl.item(count_questions);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(KEY_MCHOICE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_MCHOICE));
                map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                map.put(KEY_QUESTION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_QUESTION));                
                question_view.setText(parser.getValue(e, KEY_QUESTION));


                map.put(KEY_OPTION1, parser.getValue(e, KEY_OPTION1));
                //option1_str =parser.getValue(e, KEY_OPTION1);
                option1.setText(parser.getValue(e, KEY_OPTION1));


                map.put(KEY_OPTION2, parser.getValue(e, KEY_OPTION2));
                option2.setText(parser.getValue(e, KEY_OPTION2));
                //option2_str =parser.getValue(e, KEY_OPTION2);


                map.put(KEY_OPTION3, parser.getValue(e, KEY_OPTION3));
                option3.setText(parser.getValue(e, KEY_OPTION3));
                //option3_str =parser.getValue(e, KEY_OPTION3);


                map.put(KEY_OPTION4, parser.getValue(e, KEY_OPTION4));
                option4.setText(parser.getValue(e, KEY_OPTION4));
                //option4_str =parser.getValue(e, KEY_OPTION4);


                map.put(KEY_ANSWER,  parser.getValue(e, KEY_ANSWER));
//              makeAToast(parser.getValue(e, KEY_ANSWER));
                answer_str =parser.getValue(e, KEY_ANSWER);
                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                menuItems.add(map);
            }
```

Now, what I want to do is that, when the user gives a right answer to a particular question and the question changes and the TextView s also re position themselves. I am providing a pictorial description of what I want to do.

Suppose, this is the **layout during the first question**:

[image: Layout during first question]

If the user selects the correct option, the next question will come up, **re locating the layout like this**:

[image: Layout during the second question]

I can not achieve this layout re positioning. What should I do to accomplish the mission?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try to `setVisibility(View.GONE)` and the inflate your new layout style!

Another Workaround would be to create LayoutParams object with the desired positioning of the buttons and apply it to the RadioGroup or the ButtonGroup!

Comment: I am not aware of either of these, can you suggest me a tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

It would be an advantage to have 2 layouts for this kind of behavior. But if that doesn't work out for you I'd suggest looking into putting all the TextViews inside a RelativeLayout and then update their relative position as well as their individual margins.

Comment: How do you suggest to do that. I am not understanding what to do